# How do I get save add functionality to work with EF4 when my key field must be unique but I set it during the web session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Here is the two important bits.  I have a taxpayerID that comes from the Current users profile, but then I want to move that value from the ASPNETDB database into my actual transaction database, so I know the value, but this code fails.  It will insert the first time and fail on every following save,

**{"A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = dr405,Constraint name = PK_*dr405*_0000000000000072 ]"}**

I've tried deleting the database to clear out any cobwebs and that did not seem to help.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public String TaxPayerID { get; set; }
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```

---

```
public void Save(DR405DBContext context, dr405 obj) 
{
    if (obj.CreateDate == null)
    {
        obj.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    obj.ModDate = DateTime.Now;

    context.Entry(obj).State = obj.TaxPayerID == null ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    obj.TaxPayerID = Tangible.Profiles.DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TaxPayerID;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The third example in the accepted answer is the trick.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate everyones responses.  I solved the issue by using third example in the accepted answer is the trick. [stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework)

I was having problems due to a general lack of knowledge about EF4 and the way it tracks changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error text, you are trying to insert item with existing Primiry key to the table.
Check the `State` property of your object. It seems that it always `EntityState.Added`

Comment: Don't hold your breath, I probably won't know until monday.

Comment: That fixed it for adding, now the saving modified fails.  It's a see saw, I can only get one operation to work. never both.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the value: `Tangible.Profiles.DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TaxPayerID`
Since you reset your `TaxPayerId` before you save. looks for me that error  comes from here.