# Most efficiently handling Create, Update, Delete with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, entity-framework-5

> **Note:** I am using Entity Framework version  5

Inside my generic repository, I have `Add`, `Edit` and `Delete` methods as below:

```
public class EntityRepository<T> : IEntityRepository<T>
    where T : class, IEntity, new() {

    readonly DbContext _entitiesContext;

    public EntityRepository(DbContext entitiesContext) {

        if (entitiesContext == null) {

            throw new ArgumentNullException("entitiesContext");
        }

        _entitiesContext = entitiesContext;
    }

    //...

    public virtual void Add(T entity) {

        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _entitiesContext.Entry<T>(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached) {

            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else {

            _entitiesContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity) {

        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _entitiesContext.Entry<T>(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached) {

            _entitiesContext.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        }

        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity) {

        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _entitiesContext.Entry<T>(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached) {

            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else {

            DbSet dbSet = _entitiesContext.Set<T>();
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think whether these methods are well implemented? Especially the `Add` method. Would it be better to implement the `Add` method as below?

```
public virtual void Add(T entity) {

    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _entitiesContext.Entry<T>(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached) {

        _entitiesContext.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
    }

    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

Comment: @CoffeeAddict It's EF 5.0.0. DB first or Code first, it doesn't matter here I guess as it's a generic repository code.

Comment: You can use newly released library which will ***automatically set the state of all entities in the entity graph***. You can read [my answer to the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework/39609020#39609020).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**For add:**

```
public bool Add<E>(E entity) where E : class
        {
            DataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
            Save();
        }
```

**For update:**

```
 public bool Update<E>(E entity) where E : class
        {
            DataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            Save();
        }
```

**For delete:**

```
 public bool Delete<E>(E entity) where E : class
        {
            DataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            Save();
        }
```

And a private `Save()` method that returns true or false so you can fallback easy in the controller depending on the result

```
private bool Save()
        {
            return DataContext.SaveChanges() > 0;                
        }
```

This is only a portion of my generic repository. It works great in enterprise applications.

**UPDATE:**

> Detach only affects the specific object passed to the method. If the
>   object being detached has related objects in the object context, those
>   objects are not detached.

EF will automatically attach detached objects in the graph when setting the state of an entity or when `SaveChanges()` is called.

I really don't know why you need to detach objects from the context. You can also use `AsNoTracking()` to load entities from the database without attaching them to the context in the first place.

Comment: What happens if the object you are passing into `Add` or `Edit` method is at the `Detached` state?

Comment: Is this in lieu of having `IDbSet<T>` properties in the DbContext or Repository?

Comment: What is the purpose of `where E : class` - not sure what to Google to find more about it?

Comment: @Cody It's a constraint so the type argument must be a reference type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Why do you need a type parameter?