# Delete parent with children in one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

I have a .NET4.0 application with Entity Framework 5.0 e Sql Server CE 4.0.

I have two entities with a one to many (parent/child) relationship. I've configured it to cascade delete on parent removal, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a simplified version of my entities:

```
    public class Account
    {
        public int AccountKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    internal class AccountMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
    {
        public AccountMap()
        {
            this.HasKey(e => e.AccountKey);
            this.Property(e => e.AccountKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
        }
    }


    public class User
    {
        public int UserKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public int AccountKey { get; set; }
    }

    internal class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            this.HasKey(e => e.UserKey);
            this.Property(e => e.UserKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();


            this.HasRequired(e => e.Account)
                .WithMany(e => e.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountKey);
        }
    }

    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext()
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();
            modelBuilder.LoadConfigurations();
        }

    }
```

The connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestDb.sdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And a simplified version of my app's workflow:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>());
        using (var context = new TestContext())
            context.Database.Initialize(false);

        Account account = null;
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            var account1 = new Account() { Name = "Account1^" };
            var user1 = new User() { Name = "User1", Account = account1 };

            context.Accounts.Add(account1);
            context.Users.Add(user1);

            context.SaveChanges();

            account = account1;
        }

        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I try to delete the parent entity, it throws:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I believe my relationship configuration is ok ([followed the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete)). I also searched for [guidelines on deleting detached entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742473/most-efficiently-handling-create-update-delete-with-entity-framework-code-firs).

I really cannot understand why that delete won't work. I want to avoid loading all the children, deleting them one by one and them deleting the parent, because there must be a better solution than that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting the state of an entity to `Deleted` and calling `DbSet<T>.Remove` for this entity are not the same.

The difference is that setting the state only changes the state of the root entity (the one you pass into `context.Entry`) to `Deleted` but not the state of related entities while `Remove` does this if the relationship is configured with cascading delete.

If you get an exception actually depends on the children (all or only a part) being attached to the context or not. This leads to a behaviour which is somewhat difficult to follow:

- If you call `Remove` you don't get an exception, no matter if children are loaded or not. There is still a difference:

  - If the children are attached to the context, EF will generate a `DELETE` statement for every attached child, then for the parent (because `Remove` did mark them all as `Deleted`)
  - If the children are not attached to the context EF will only send a `DELETE` statement for the parent to the database and because cascading delete is enabled the database will delete the children as well.
- If you set the state of the root entity to `Deleted` you can *possibly* get an exception:

  - If children are attached to the context their state won't be set to `Deleted` and EF will complain that you are trying to delete a principal (the root entity) in a required relationship without deleting the dependents (the children) or at least without setting their foreign keys to another root entity that is not in `Deleted` state. That's the exception you had: `account` is the root and `user1` is a dependent of `account` and calling `context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Deleted;` will also attach `user1` in state `Unchanged` to the context (or change detection in `SaveChanges` will do it, I'm not sure abut that). `user1` is part of the `account.Users` collection because relationship fixup added it to the collection in your first context although you didn't add it explicitly in your code.
  - If no children are attached to the context setting the state of the root to `Deleted` will send a `DELETE` statement to the database and again cascading delete in the database will delete the children as well. This works without exception. Your code would then work for example if you set `account.Users = null` before setting the state to `Deleted` in the second context or before entering the second context.

In my opinion using `Remove`...

```cs
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.Accounts.Attach(account);
    context.Accounts.Remove(account);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

...is clearly the prefered way because the behaviour of `Remove` is much more like you would expect for a required relationship with cascading delete (which is the case in your model). The dependency of the behaviour of a manual state change on states of other entities makes it more difficult to use. I would consider it as advanced usage only for special cases.

The difference is not widely known or documented. I've seen very few posts about it. The only one that I could find right now again, is [this one by Zeeshan Hirani](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5e53a469-1175-47d7-84bf-9a1a28dfd145/).

Comment: Very enlightening, @Slauma! I searched a lot for some clue prior to posting the question but I had not found the post you mentioned. Thank you

Comment: It seems that many people are having so many issues when trying to make parent-child operations work in EF such as insert, update and delete that every time I read more about EF, the more disappointed I get.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a slight different approach and, strangely, it worked. If I replace this code:

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

By this one:

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    context.Accounts.Remove(account);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It works with no further problems. Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm missing something. I really would appreciate some light over the matter, because I was pretty sure that the first way (EntityState.Deleted) was the recommeded one.