# Can i have only one method to delete record from passed table name and id using Entity Framework and Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Suppose we have some tables having Primary Key named "id". Is it possible to create only one method which gets table name and id to delete the record?

Comment: Please include more details about your problem, and include the code you've written so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742473/most-efficiently-handling-create-update-delete-with-entity-framework-code-firs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public bool Delete<E>(E entity) where E : class
    {
        DataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
        DataContext.SaveChanges()
    }
```

With Generic definition of a method you can , as done above.

Deleting a record using entity framework is by marking entity state of an object as deleted.

more on this here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742919/1018054

Hope that helps ! :)

Comment: Thanks @vishal sharma

Comment: wc @Atul , I'm glad that helps you.