# How to add multiple new rows to a DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My question seems similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140617/update-and-add-child-rows-at-same-time-with-entity-framework) but the exact details as well as the solution seem to have changed over the years.  (For one thing, the `ObjectStateManager` referenced in the accepted answer is apparently no longer accessible.)

I have a web app that displays an object graph. One of the objects in the graph is a list.  The user can edit the items in the list.  They can also add new items.  When they save their changes, I serialize the whole object graph (including a field indicating whether values were added or modified) and send it to a controller to update the database.  I send the added items with uninitialized IDs.  In the controller, I deserialize the object graph and pass it to `DbContext#Attach()`. Then I set the entity states of the attached entries before calling `SaveChanges()`.

This works with any number of changed rows, and it works with a single added row. The database assigns an ID when a row is inserted. But `Attach()` does not accept multiple added rows with the same uninitialized ID.

Is there a way to suppress the validation of IDs in `Attach()`? It seems like EF should leave that up to the database.  Failing that, how should I go about this?

Comment: Do you have `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` attribute?

Comment: @cassandrad Yes.