# Add record to DbContext by returning null with a query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I did a research I not found anything so far. Appreciate your help.

As the title says, I'm adding a record to my DbContext by doing a query, and if it returns a null value then I create the record. Otherwise, I modify it.

My question is: Is this a good practice or I shouldn't do this that way? The code is like this:

```
var desiredEntity = MyDbContext.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Rob");

if (desiredEntity == null)
  { desiredEntity = new DbSetOfEntity()... //create if doesn't exists }
else
{ desiredEntity.ValueToModify == 3; }

MyDbContext.SaveChanges()
```

What is the difference between this and creating an entity explicitly and adding it with the DbContext.Add() method?

**Edit:**
A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework) is asked, but I don't want to use AddOrUpdate method or Attach and changing the state of the entities manually. I just want to know if my approach is not problematic and what are the differences by using the conventional .Add(myEntity) approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Row if it Exists Else Insert Logic with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework)

Comment: Nope, I don't need Attach method or AddOrUpdate method. I edited the question, just want to know something about my approach :) And it would be great if someone has some link to documentation about this.

Comment: I'm not following why you don't want to use AddOrUpdate. But what you're doing is not necessarily a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

`AddOrUpdate()` is checking record for existance by EntityKey. So if `x.Name` which you are checking is not Key - your approach is correct.

Also as you have only name value as an input parameter ("Rob") you will have to request record from context, and you will have it attached. So then you can just change it as you need and the changes will be tracked automatically. Alternatively, create it if it doesn't exist and call `Add()`.

Taking into account the above your approach is OK and will work and I dont see any problems with it.

On the other hand, your code should be as simple and elegant as it can be. It is important for supporting your code by you or by your teammates. That is why using constructions like `AddOrUpdate` or other built-in stuff is good practice. But not a law.

P.S. I am not looking at code like `{ desiredEntity.ValueToModify == 3; }`. This is potentially bad practice as 3 should perhaps be passed to your method as a parameter.