# MVC check if record exists before adding to table

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've got following problem. If I'm inserting a record to my database tables with dbcontext each time a new record gets created. 
So for example if Stadt and Postleitzahl are already existing in table my application should take the Id property of the record insteat of creating a new auto generated Id with same Postleitzahl and Stadt values.
Where am I going wrong?
My Create Method in Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateKundeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var kunde = new Kunde()
            {
                Vorname = viewModel.Vorname,
                Nachname = viewModel.Nachname,
                Strasse = viewModel.Strasse,
                Hausnummer = viewModel.Hausnummer,
                Email = viewModel.Email,
                Telefon = viewModel.Telefon,
                AGB = viewModel.AGB,
                Whatsapp = viewModel.Whatsapp,
                Web = viewModel.Web,
                Aktiv = viewModel.Aktiv
            };

            var anrede = new Anrede()
            {
                AnredeText = viewModel.Anrede,
                AnredeTyp = 1
            };


            var stadt = new Stadt()
            { 
                Ort = viewModel.Ort,
                Postleitzahl = viewModel.Postleitzahl
            };

            var hund = new Hund()
            {
                Name = viewModel.HundName,
                Groesse = viewModel.Groesse,
                Gewicht = viewModel.Gewicht,
                Geburtsdatum = viewModel.Geburtsdatum

            };

            var rasse = new Rasse()
            {
                Rassename = viewModel.Rassename
            };

            var kastriert = new Kastriert()
            {
                Kastrierttyp = viewModel.Kastriertname
            };

            var geschlecht = new Geschlecht()
            {
                Geschlechtstyp = viewModel.Geschlecht
            };

            _context.Anredes.Add(anrede);
             _context.Stadts.Add(stadt);
             _context.Kundes.Add(kunde);
             _context.Rasses.Add(rasse);
             _context.Kastrierts.Add(kastriert);
             _context.Geschlechts.Add(geschlecht);
             _context.Hunds.Add(hund);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Kunde");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the record already exsits and then add it, like this:

```
if(_context.Kundes.Count(e => e.Vorname== kunde.Vorname)==0)
{
 _context.Kundes.Add(kunde);
}
```

Comment: When I'm using this I'm getting an exepction error, when the record already exists. How can I tell Entity Framework only to insert the value if it's not existing otherwise use the existing value?

Comment: Can you tell what the exception message is?

Comment: I unfortunally cannot add a screenshot as a commet but i'm getting the message "SQL Exeption the INSERT Statement detected a conflict with foreign key "FK_dbo.Kundes_dbo.Stadts.Stadt_Id. Th conflict was detected in database table dbo.Stadts" if the Ort or Postleitzahl (ZIPCode) already exists in the database.

Comment: The problem is in the values you're trying to add maybe this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965837/insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-sql-server

Answer (score -1):

If you are using EntityFramework 4.3, you can use `AddOrUpdate` method, which is under `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` namespace.

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(
    this IDbSet<TEntity> set,
    params TEntity[] entities
)
where TEntity : class
```

Please use the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for reference

If you are using older version of Entity Framework, this link may helps

[Update Row if it Exists Else Insert Logic with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework)

Comment: Thanks for your response! How do I have to use it? Is TEntity the place holder for my dbcontext?

Comment: May be this article will help http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Comment: Like it is mentioned in the link, this method should not be used in the code. It is only to be used while seeding in code first approach. @RajN