# How can I update row if it exists otherwise add it into the database? [EntityFramework]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table called Customers. On my website, the customer fills in his first name, last name, and email. I want to check if the email already exists in the database by what the customer fills in. If the customer exists, I would like to update the first name and last name (if they are different from the database).

The code I'm currently using for this is as following:

```
var email = vm.Reservation.Customer.Email; 

var customer = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Email == email).First();
if(customer != null)
{
    db.Entry(customer).State = !db.Customers.Any(c => c.Email == customer.Email) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
} else { 
    db.Customers.Add(vm.Reservation.Customer);
}

vm.Save();
```

However, it results in just adding a new customer with the modified username and password in the database with the same email.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Row if it Exists Else Insert Logic with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email);

if(customer != null)
{
    //Set the values of 'customer' object using 'vm.Reservation.Customer'
    customer.Email = vm.Reservation.Customer.Email;
    customer.Field1 = vm.Reservation.Customer.Field1;
    customer.Field2 = vm.Reservation.Customer.Field2;

    db.Customers.Update(vm.Reservation.Customer);
} 
else { 
    db.Customers.Add(vm.Reservation.Customer);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Note: This code works for EntityFramework with PostgreSql database.
So please mention your database you are using, which will be easier for you to find answers.

Comment: It returns the error "DbSet<Customer> does not contain a defenition for 'Update' and no accessible extension method 'Update' accepting a first argument of type DbSet<Customer> @DiluFerz

Comment: What is the EF version you are using?

Comment: I have EntityFramework 6.1.3 @DiluzFerz

Comment: @Wolf What is your database ? SQL, MySqul, PostgreSql, etc?  
Because the above code works fine for EntityFramework with PostgreSql.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var email = vm.Reservation.Customer.Email; 
var customer = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();

if(customer != null)
{
     customer.FirstName=vm.Reservation.Customer.FirstName; 
     customer.LastName=vm.Reservation.Customer.LastName; 
    db.Entry(customer).State =  EntityState.Modified;
} 
else 
{ 
    db.Customers.Add(vm.Reservation.Customer);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```